# The issue with re import jar to domino database

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

When you import jar at the first time all is good, but when you make some changes and trying to re import your jar you realized that your old jar is stored somewhere and you can't delete it. I tried do this by hands, by synchronizing from local disk, by replication, nothing helps.

May be someone knows how to delete old jar and import the new one.

I know that when you rename new jar all is good. But I don't want to change version of my jar just because I don't know something about notes database.

Comment: Where do you use the jar - in XPages or Agent?

Comment: I use in REST service (ServiceBean). So it's Xpages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restart your HTTP task on Domino server after you changed a jar with server console command

```
restart task http
```

Otherwise the old version will still be used by JVM.

As an alternative you could add a version number to your jar like `my-classes-1.0.1.jar`. Then Domino knows that the new jar has to be used.

Comment: I have asked about other ways. I understand that if I restart http task or rename I'll have success. I was hoping that I don't know some other way.

Comment: I think there are no other ways. The problem lies inside the JVM. You can't  manipulate the current loaded jars from outside.

Comment: So when I need to roll back my jar to elder version I have to restart http task on server. The easiest way work with domino is storing your java code in .java files:) But it's very convenient to make some jar and import to domino from intellij idea. But if I have some immediate changes I can make some temporary name.

Comment: Yes, this would be the approach for production servers. I always use restart task http when I am working with my development server though. That's just easier.

Answer (score 0):

In IBM Domino Designer select your project then chose from navigation *Project>Clean...*. Chose your project and then click *OK*.

Comment: It doesn't help. Like all developers who works with xpages I use clean quite often.

Answer (score 0):

I found that after I imported a JAR I had to restart Designer, otherwise, it was not finding the classes in my Jar. After the restart it worked fine.